# How can I enable Assembly binding logging?

Tags: registry, regedit, assemblybinding, ysod

I'm getting, "Could not load file or assembly 'Bla' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

A portion of the detailed info says:

*"WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]."*

So, thinking this may give me some insight in why I'm getting the error above (maybe the next YSOD would contain more explicit information about exactly why it's failing), I navigated to that location in the registry, but there is no such key that I can see. What it does have is:

```
\Fusion 
    (Default)   value not set
    \GACChangeNotification
    \NativeImagesIndex
    \PublisherPolicy
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A good place to start your investigation into any failed binding is to use the "fuslogvw.exe" utility. This may give you the information you need related to the binding failure so that you don't have to go messing around with any registry values to turn binding logging on.

[Fuslogvw MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The utility should be in your Microsoft SDKs folder, which would be something like this, depending on your operating system:
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v{SDK version}A\Bin\FUSLOGVW.exe"*

1. Run this utility **as Administrator**, from Developer Command Prompt (as Admin) type `FUSLOGVW` a new screen appears
2. Go to **Settings** to and select **Enable all binds to disk** also select **Enable custom log path** and select the path of the folder of your choice to store the binding log.
3. Restart IIS.
4. From the FUSLOGVW window click **Delete all** to clear the list of any previous bind failures
5. Reproduce the binding failure in your application
6. In the utility, click **Refresh**. You should then see the bind failure logged in the list.
7. You can view information about the bind failure by selecting it in the list and clicking **View Log**

The first thing I look for is the path in which the application is looking for the assembly. You should also make sure the version number of the assembly in question is what you expect.

Comment: If the settings are readonly, try running the tool as administrator

Comment: Good answer but it didn't show any bind failures for me, even after I enabled logging of all bindings...

Comment: You could try setting the log path to a specific folder that you have access to. I've run into permissions related issues before. I just created an empty folder, gave permissions to everyone and pointed fuslogvw at it to get it working.

Comment: If you're building an ASP.NET MVC application (or possibly any other application involving IIS) restarting IIS was required to get the binding logs.

Comment: if you see nothing in the log viewer then you can go to the settings and select "Enable all binds to disk". Then create a folder to which you can give all permissions. In the 'Log Settings' window where you just selected, check "Enable custom log path" and the path of the folder you just created. Restart IIS and browse to your site. You can see the logging now.

Comment: FYI, I had to clear out my Internet Explorer cache by deleting temporary internet files.  I don't even use Internet Explorer.  See the note at the bottom of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In later versions of .net you can also select "Log exeption text" and it just puts the error in the exception, no log required.

Comment: Downvoted, this is not the answer to the posted question.

Comment: @motoDrizzt feel free to EDIT it and add what you consider an answer.

Answer (score 31):

Just create a new DWORD(32) under the Fusion key. Name the DWORD to EnableLog, and set it to value 1. Then restart IIS, refresh the page giving errors, and the assembly bind logs will show in the error message.

Exact registry path is `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]`. You can copy next text into a new file `EnableLog.reg` and double click the file.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]
"EnableLog"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: How to create DWORD(32) ?

Comment: Using regedit, navigate to the Fusion key. Right click in the empty space in the right-side pane. Expand "New" and you will see "DWORD(32-bit) Value" there.

Answer (score 12):

1. Create a new Application Pool
2. Go to the Advanced Settings of this application pool
3. Set the Enable 32-Bit Application to True
4. Point your web application to use this new Pool

[image: Screenshot (IIS-ApplicationPool)]

Comment: This is not what the op asked for... This config will just force the web app to run as x32, even on an x64 system. A DLL compiled as x64 running in this app can be the root problem, but this setting has far more impact than just solving the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For me the 'Bla' file was System.Net.http dll which was missing from my BIN folder. I just added it and it worked fine. Didn't change any registry key or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 2):

Per pierce.jason's answer above, I had luck with:

Just create a new DWORD(32) under the Fusion key. Name the DWORD to **LogFailures**, and set it to value 1. Then restart IIS, refresh the page giving errors, and the assembly bind logs will show in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Creating New Application Pool,You can go to your
 Existing **application Pool**->**Right click Advance setting->Enable 32-bit Application**-----Set to **TRUE**

Answer (score 1):

If you sometimes run different versions of your application, make sure you delete 'Bla' from the application bin directory if the version running doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes for me in windows application while calling server dll from client. After system restart it works fine

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue resolved when I cleaned the solution and build it again. Worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem I fixed it by deleting the existing `key.snk` in that project and adding a new key.