# "Could not load file or assembly" when building using team city

Tags: .net, unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, .net-assembly

I'm running into an issue with unit tests on our Team City (8.0.4) build server - the code builds & runs all tests locally via Resharper and nCrunch.

But when running on the server I get the following error, even though the Unity assembly exists in the same directory as the unit test assembly, and is referenced in the unit test assembly.

> SetUp method failed. SetUp : System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at XXXX.Unity.UnityContainerAdapter..ctor()
>      at XXXX.GraphExtensionsTests..ctor() in c:\TeamCityV7\Agent-1\work\f02f7e27c0bedfa2\XXXX\Graph.Tests\Extensions\GraphExtensionsTests.cs:line 44

I've confirmed the copy of Microsoft.Practices.Unity is the correct version.

I've also confirmed the assemblies are built using the full version of the framework - not using client profile.

Any ideas why Team City might be failing?

Comment: Are you using the NuGet package for Unity? If not I would recommend that you do as I've found that a lot of these reference issues become much more straigtforward when using NuGet.

Comment: I 'would' if I could but constrained by politics...

Comment: If you want some insight as to where it's looking for the 'missing' assembly, you can use a windows utility called fuslogvw, [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681432/how-can-i-enable-assembly-binding-logging/17682082#17682082).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the pattern you're using to locate your test assemblies.  I had a similar problem with another library and it turns out the pattern was finding the test assembly under bin\Release and obj\Release; the obj folder doesn't contain all the assemblies referenced by the project and is really just a scratch folder for the compiler.

Comment: Bingo! There was a rogue test assembly referenced by another test assembly and it was running the rogue assembly tests as well.

Comment: Nice one, that did the job! :)

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by changing my **Test file names** pattern from `**\*.Tests.dll` to `**\bin\**\*.Tests.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility I recently discovered is if you are using a library that you are not explicitly referencing, TeamCity will not collect the library for use and fail when it is implicitly referencing the assembly.  I discovered this when trying to figure out why NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, which was referenced in my test project, was not being loaded and resulting in a FileNotFoundException on TeamCity.  Ultimately, I made a "dummy" unit test like so:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CastleProxyPresenceTest
    {

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Infrastructure: This test forces TeamCity to load the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll file.")]
        public void CastleProxyLoads()
        {
            var dummy = new LazyFieldInterceptor();
            Assert.IsNotNull(dummy);
        }
    }
}
```

...after this, the file loaded properly and my unit tests compiled.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to nuke your local copy of the repository and clone it anew. If you're deploying a branch, switch to that branch before you restore packages and build for the first time. You will get a better clue about the real reason for the problem.

One possibility not listed here is if your test project is a Framework project, but there is a .NET Standard project in the same solution, the test project may not be able to find the package references for the Standard project on a clean clone / restore / build.