# How to make TeamCity see the file referenced?

Tags: nunit, teamcity-8.0

Locally run, everything works just fine. When I execute a test from TeamCity I get the following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.Lib, Version=2.0.5288.17943, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'XXX.Lib, Version=2.0.5288.17943, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

To remedy it, I checked that the file is referenced. I also checked in the properties that *Copy Local* is set to *true* and that *Path* is pointing to *C:\TFS...* where my version control resides.

Apparently, the file doesn't get to the right position and I'm at a loss because I don't know how to make it do what I want. Suggestions?

I strongly suspect that it's similar to [this issue, right here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164646/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-when-building-using-team-city) but I've got no idea:
1. how to get the information on **where** TC looks for the DLL, nor
2. How to enforce the correct path on it to look at.

Comment: On your build server, have a look in the Checkout directory at the \bin\$(configuration) folder for your test project. MSBuild should have copied over all the referenced libraries as specified in your project file. Is it missing from here? What about the library-under-test's \bin\$(configuration) folder, is the missing library in there?

Comment: @mattyB Put that as a reply so I can check the answer green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your build server, have a look in the Checkout directory at the \bin\$(configuration) folder for your test project. MSBuild should have copied over all the referenced libraries as specified in your project file.

If it's missing from there, try checking the library-under-test's \bin\$(configuration) folder, and then in turn the project file for that library.